# SQL Server Spatial convert from Linestring to Polygon

Tags: sql-server, spatial, spatial-query

Can someone help me with convert SQL Server Geometry Shape object to Geometry Polygon object.

I have have a Shape object which is of "Ohio state plan south" coordinate with SRID 32123 and I want to convert it to Geometry Polygon with SRID 3857

This is what I have so far... when I am running it getting below error.

***Error: "24119: The Polygon input is not valid because the start and end points of the exterior ring are not the same. Each ring of a polygon must have the same start and end points."***

```
DECLARE @predata varchar(MAX) = 'LINESTRING (544447.66750002524 219649.36696754955, 544446.556000026 219690.21900326665, 544443.99000002549 219720.61000326276, 544435.09000002721 219836.23000326566, 544431.66000001959 219896.72000326123, 544430.0600000252 219924.97000326123, 544422.56000002555 219999.65000326186, 544419.05563904892 220098.02782277763)';
DECLARE @data geometry;
DECLARE @linestring geometry = @predata;
DECLARE @srid int;
SET @predata = REPLACE(@predata, 'LINESTRING', 'POLYGON(') + ')';
SELECT @predata AS PolygonString

SET @data = geometry::STGeomFromText(@predata, 3857);
SELECT @data AS GeographyPolygon
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you what the problem is. That is, polygons need to start and end with the same point. Your linestring does not (starts at `544447.66750002524 219649.36696754955`, ends at `544419.05563904892 220098.02782277763`). I was able to get it to work by taking the starting point of the linestring and appending it to the end. If this is a one-time operation, that should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

As agreed with the previous answer please simply use your scripts with a bit change shown as below:

```
--start point should be same as end point
DECLARE @predata varchar(MAX) = 'LINESTRING (
544447.66750002524 219649.36696754955, 
544446.556000026 219690.21900326665, 
544443.99000002549 219720.61000326276, 
544435.09000002721 219836.23000326566, 
544431.66000001959 219896.72000326123, 
544430.0600000252 219924.97000326123, 
544422.56000002555 219999.65000326186, 
544447.66750002524 219649.36696754955)'; 
--end point should be same as start point
DECLARE @data geometry;
DECLARE @linestring geometry = @predata;
DECLARE @srid int;
SET @predata = REPLACE(@predata, 'LINESTRING', 'POLYGON(') + ')';
SELECT @predata AS PolygonString
SET @data = geometry::STGeomFromText(@predata, 3857);
SELECT @data AS GeographyPolygon
```