# Extract polygon inside linestrings SQL Server spatial

Tags: sql, sql-server, polygon, spatial

I have thousands of SQL Server geography linestrings which draw boundaries of counties. Since the don't form polygons, I cannot use a T-SQL query with `STContains(@point)`.

How can I extract a polygon surrounded by linestrings?

`STContains(@point)` or `STIntersects(@point)` always return null.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Spatial convert from Linestring to Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67876630/sql-server-spatial-convert-from-linestring-to-polygon)

Comment: nope, i have spatial data like 0xE6100000010403000000A8B30BA2B5654240F14ADC291D9841401E12A2BE2C66424055570A5394974140DCA4A8889A6642408980ECFF1C97414001000000010000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000002

Comment: So a country boundary is just a bunch of linestrings that together enclose some polygon area? you can create a polygon from those by concating line string points and forming an enclosed area. Of course, the linestrings must be ordered in a way that allows proper concating, or at least they should start from the other's end points

Comment: I would suggest find some better boundaries, there are geopackages available with proper polygons, your storage format is awful and will probably just give you grief in the long run.

Comment: oh btw, NULLs can mean that your srid don't match. You should add a real example of your code before this gets closed

Comment: The article that Roger Wolf linked is your answer, but you need a few extra steps. (1) Cast your hex (binary) data to a Geography type. (2) Convert to text using `.ToString()`, yielding a string of the form "LINESTRING(x1 y1, x2 y3, ..., xn yn)". (3) Strip off the outer "LINESTRING(...)" syntax, leaving just the coordinates. (4) If you last coordinates do not match the first, you will need to extract and duplicate the start point as the endpoint. (5) Wrap the coordinates back up into a "POLYGON((...))". (Note the double parantheses.) (6) convert back to geography with `STGeomFromText()`.

Comment: Be careful with confusing the geometry and geography types. Geography uses a non-Euclidean spheroid. Geometry uses a flat Euclidean coordinate system, and is generally not suitable for global mapping operations.  Also be aware that your source geometry may gave more than one outer boundary (think islands) and possibly one or more inner boundaries (think lakes and Vatican City). By convention (right-hand-rule), outer boundaries will have a counterclockwise boundary and positive area, while inner boundaries (voids) will have clockwise boundaries and negative area.  See STArea().

Answer (score 1):

The article that Roger Wolf linked is your answer, but you need a few extra steps.

1. Cast your hex (binary) data to a geography type.
2. Convert to text using `.ToString()`, yielding a string of the form "LINESTRING(x1 y1, x2 y3, ..., xn yn)".
3. Strip off the outer "LINESTRING(...)" syntax, leaving just the coordinates.
4. If your last coordinate pair does not match the first, you will need to extract and duplicate the start point as the endpoint.
5. Wrap the coordinates back up into a "POLYGON((...))". *Note the double parentheses.*
6. Convert back to geography with `STGeomFromText()`.

The following shows this process step-by-step using the supplied sample data:

```
-- OP supplied sample linestring
DECLARE @binaryData VARBINARY(MAX) = 0xE6100000010403000000A8B30BA2B5654240F14ADC291D9841401E12A2BE2C66424055570A5394974140DCA4A8889A6642408980ECFF1C97414001000000010000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000002

-- Convert binary to geography
-- The sample linestring has a slight clockwise turn, so produces a reverse sense polygon
DECLARE @linestring GEOGRAPHY = @binaryData
SELECT @linestring.ToString() AS Linestring
  
-- Convert to Linestring WKT, reformat as Polygon WKT and convert back to geography
DECLARE @linestringWkt VARCHAR(MAX) = @linestring.ToString()
DECLARE @linestringCoordinates VARCHAR(MAX)
    = REPLACE(REPLACE(@linestringWkt, 'LINESTRING (', ''), ')', '')
DECLARE @commaPos INT = CHARINDEX(', ', @linestringCoordinates)
DECLARE @startPoint VARCHAR(MAX) = LEFT(@linestringCoordinates, @commaPos - 1)
DECLARE @polygonCoordinates VARCHAR(MAX) = @linestringCoordinates + ', ' + @startPoint
DECLARE @polygonWkt VARCHAR(MAX) = 'POLYGON((' + @polygonCoordinates + '))'
DECLARE @srid INT = @linestring.STSrid -- Use the SRID from the original object
DECLARE @polygon GEOGRAPHY = Geography::STGeomFromText(@polygonWkt, @srid)

-- Display resulting geography WKT and area
DECLARE @aream2 FLOAT = @polygon.STArea() -- Square meters
DECLARE @areakm2 FLOAT = @aream2 / 1000000 -- Square kilometers
SELECT @areakm2 AS AreaSquareKm, @polygon.ToString() AS WKT

-- If we have an outer polygon showing an area greater than
-- half of the earth's surface (0.5 * 510.1 million sq km = 255e12 sq meters),
-- we have a clockwise (negative) polygon and we need to reverse the sense.
IF (@polygon.STArea() > 255e+12)
BEGIN
    SET @polygon = @polygon.ReorientObject()
    -- Display resulting geography WKT and area
    SET @aream2 = @polygon.STArea() -- Square meters
    SET @areakm2 = @aream2 / 1000000 -- Square kilometers
    SELECT @areakm2 AS AreaSquareKm, @polygon.ToString() AS WKT
END
```

The above can be reduced by combining several of the expressions. The intent here was to shown each of the steps in detail.

Results:

| Linestring |
| --- |
| LINESTRING (35.1883899999283 36.7946054989946, 35.184214000749 36.7982404986726, 35.1805725006862 36.8015909980256) |

| AreaSquareKm | WKT |
| --- | --- |
| 510065621.70725 | POLYGON ((35.1883899999283 36.7946054989946, 35.184214000749 36.7982404986726, 35.1805725006862 36.8015909980256, 35.1883899999283 36.7946054989946)) |

The sample data represents a 3 point linestring with a slight right-turn. The resulting polygon is therefore a clockwise path. Instead of enclosing a small area, it is treated as enclosing the inverse - nearly the whole earth's surface (5.1 million km^2) excluding just the small area. Reversing the sense of the polygon with `ReorientObject()` yields a polygon enclosing just 0.0037 km^2.

| AreaSquareKm | WKT |
| --- | --- |
| 0.003746545378685 | POLYGON ((35.1805725006862 36.8015909980256, 35.184214000749 36.7982404986726, 35.1883899999283 36.7946054989946, 35.1805725006862 36.8015909980256)) |

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_WClscK1) that shows conversion of original OP supplied sample data and another case representing the US State of Colorado corner points.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @GEO GEOMETRY = 0xE6100000010403000000A8B30BA2B5654240F14ADC291D9841401E12A2BE2C66424055570A5394974140DCA4A8889A6642408980ECFF1C97414001000000010000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000002

SELECT @GEO.STEnvelope().STAsText()
```

Comment: STEnvelope "returns the minimum axis-aligned bounding rectangle of the instance." I think that might be overstating the country boundary. STConvexHull is closer, but will also overstating the country boundary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too

```
DECLARE @GEO GEOMETRY = 0xE6100000010403000000A8B30BA2B5654240F14ADC291D9841401E12A2BE2C66424055570A5394974140DCA4A8889A6642408980ECFF1C97414001000000010000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000002

SELECT @GEO.ToString()
```